# How can I run a provider-hosted app automatically every given-time-period?

Tags: workflow, azure

I have created a provider hosted app that runs in Azure. The app is responsible for getting external data into a SharePoint list. What are the options in getting the app to run automatically, let's say every 15 minutes? Can I accomplish this with a workflow?
Or is there another way to schedule in SharePoint?

My app is deployed on SharePoint Online

Update:
The scenario I'd like to accomplish is that the service in Azure can be called from multiple site collections. So if the app is installed in 3 site collections, then each one can call the service in Azure, and all that the Azure service will know is that it has been invoked. The app will determine when and with what credentials and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a list workflow that updated an item in the list every 15 minutes. Then in my Azure app I created an event receiver that started the app whenever the it received note that the item was changed in the list.